# Condition based on duplicate elements in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists

```
my_list = [['1996', 0.23, 0.56], ['1997', 0.45, 0.32], ['1996', 0.15, 0.34],['1997', 0.34, 0.13]]
```

I need to write it to as a text file so that it looks like

```
1996|Area|None|0.23|0.56

1997|Area|None|0.45|0.32

1996|Area|Metro|0.15|0.34

1997|Area|Metro|0.34|0.13
```

I wrote the following code

```
for data in my_list:
    data.insert(1, Area)
    data.insert(2, None)
    file.write("|".join(map(str, data)) + '\n')
```

How ever this isn't giving me the right output, how do I change the 'None' value to "Metro" whenever I encounter '1996' again.

Thanks for the help

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri While the year 1996 is not encountered the second time the 2, 3 position remains Area and None, when it is encountered the next time i need the 3 rd element to change from None to metro and continue as such until 1996 is encountered again and so on

Answer (score 2):

You should create a temporary `list` (or `set`)to keep a track of the years which are added and set the "None" and "Metro" accordingly:

- if year is in the list, set "Metro"
- if year is not in the list, add year to the list and set "None"

Hence your code should be like:

```
year_list = []
for data in my_list:
    year = data[0]
    data.insert(1, Area)
    if year in year_list:
        data.insert(2, "Metro")
    else:
        data.insert(2, None)
        year_list.append(year)
    file.write("|".join(map(str, data)) + '\n')
```

Comment: this appends metro to all the other entries, every time I encounter 1996 the metro also needs to be changed accordingly from a list of metros.

Comment: @ArnabSharma Isn't that the right behavior as per what you mentioned in the questioned *"how do I change the 'None' value to "Metro" whenever I encounter '1996' again."*. Also there is no mention of `metro` as list. All I see is the "Metro" string mentioned here.

Comment: @ArnabSharma If you want different result then what you mentioned here, please open a new question, but I try to achieve it by yourself first. It'll help you learn new stuff

Comment: @ArnabSharma Editing the question will make the current answers incorrect. I can edit mine, but the other answer won't be valid any longer. That's why it is better to create the new question in such scenarios

Comment: Actually the metros were in a list, I apologize for not making the question unclear, however opening a similar question has the risk of it being marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use a set so you can know which years have already been in your data.

```
year_set = set()

for data in my_list:
    data.insert(1, Area)
    if data[0] in year_set:
        data.insert(2, 'Metro')
    else:
        data.insert(2, None)
        year_set.add(data[0])
    file.write("|".join(map(str, data)) + '\n')
```